# Python script to check for files in directories then email me the names

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, smtp

So as the title suggests I'm new to Python and my first project is a script that will check 5 directories for teh existence of a specific file.  If exists I want it to email me the filenames it found in each path.

Here is what I have so far..

```
    from pathlib import *


adr01_file = Path("/home/skeer/Documents/Projects/Python_temp/home/adr01/upload/monitor*.pgp")
if adr01_file.is_file():
    print("File exists")
else:
    print("File does not exist")


chpt_file = Path("/home/skeer/Documents/Projects/Python_temp/home/chpt/upload/monitor*.pgp")
if adr01_file.is_file():
    print("File exists")
else:
    print("File does not exist")


emb01_file = Path("/home/skeer/Documents/Projects/Python_temp/home/emb01/upload/monitor*.pgp")
if adr01_file.is_file():
    print("File exists")
else:
    print("File does not exist")


exp01_file = Path("/home/skeer/Documents/Projects/Python_temp/home/exp01/upload/monitor*.pgp")
if adr01_file.is_file():
    print("File exists")
else:
    print("File does not exist")


iix01_file = Path("/home/skeer/Documents/Projects/Python_temp/home/iix01/upload/monitor*.pgp")
if adr01_file.is_file():
    print('File exists')
else:
    print('File does not exist')
```

But what I get is 'File exists' for every line.  Even when there is no file in any directory except the adr01 one.

All hints/tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're checking for existence of `adr01_file` five times - you forgot to change variable in your `if` statements. Also, I see `*` in your paths - did you mean it literally or as a wildcard? If the later, it won't work.

Comment: Yeah I had hoped to use a wildcard in the file name value but I guess that idea is out of the window unless I switch to globs.

Comment: Ugh, the typos.  I just started using PyCharm.. I think I hit a wrong button that undid some changes I made.  Thanks for being another set of eyes.